# Javascript repeated use of "new" with same target variable

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, garbage

I think this is OK but I would like confirmation.

In Javascript can I repeatedly assign a new object to the same variable without causing memory leaks or other problems?

Example:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(left1, top1, width1, height1);
...
...
... // some stuff
...
rect = new Rectangle(left2, top2, width2, height2); // change the rect size
...
...
... // some other stuff
...
rect = new Rectangle(left3, top3, width3, height3); // change the rect size again
```

The Rectangle class just holds a representation of a rectangle, including a few parameters calculated from the passed ones. I think the garbage collection will take care of it but as a C++ chap that repeated use of "new" makes me nervous!

Comment: I think garbage collection will clear the memory) So don't care about this)

Comment: It's not a memory leak, but maybe inefficient. Have you considered reusing the existing object? Just assign new properties to it. Or use `Rectangle.call(rect, left2, top2, width2, height2);` for a re-initialisation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'd already reworked the code to be more efficient but I'm still new to javascript so I needed to make sure I understand how the garbage collection would behave in that scenario. Thanks all for speedy response.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has garbage collection, so you can safely assign new objects to the same variable.
When an object becomes unaccessible it will be garbage collected.